# How to Run react app from express server?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express

How to run the react page  index.html  from express server 3000 port?I am new to react...so really need help in this.
Please find the screenshot of my server.js page.
[image]

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It's not quite clear from the screenshot what is in public/index.html. Do you have any troubles with seeing index.html from http://localhost:3000?

Anyway, you should configure your React application built in a way that it puts the output static files into the public folder and serve it from there with `express.static` as you're currently doing. If you're new to this, try generating your React application with `create-react-app` and get the build process configured for you.